# Component mounts several times, but only renders once

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component:

```
class Swatch1 extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("MERCHANT");
    console.log(this.props.merchant);
    }

lightestColor(colors) {
// Color calculations that set highestColor
console.log(highestColor);
}

  render() { 

    return (

  <ColorExtractor
    src={this.props.merchant.merchant.coverPhoto}
    getColors={colors => this.lightestColor(colors)}
  />

);
}
}

// mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps here

// Redux connection
const Swatch = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Swatch1);
```

Now this component is being called every time another component is rendered, and for my current use-case, it should be being rendered three times...

Other component:

```
class Card extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

    <div className="card titlecard" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.merchant.merchant.coverPhoto})`}}>
<Swatch merchant={this.props.merchant.merchant} />
....
```

CardRow component in it's entirely, including how the '' objects are being added.

```
class CardRow extends Component {

list = []

componentWillMount() {
  this.list.push(<Card merchant={this.props.merchant} />)
}

    render() {

      return (
        <div className="App">

          <ScrollMenu
            data={this.list}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Right now, this is creating three `<CardRow />` objects.

So theoretically, every time CardRow is rendered, Card (and thus Swatch1) should be rendered, and this seems to be consistent with componentWillMount() in Swatch1, but NOT lightestColor().

Why is componentWillMount() correctly being called multiple times, but not lightestColor()?

Shouldn't they both be called each time the Swatch1 component renders (which should be 3 times?)

Comment: "Why is componentWillMount() correctly being called multiple times, but not lightestColor()?" Why do you expect `lightestColor` to be called multiple times ? I don't see any call to this function, I only see the function declaration. By the way I don't see any declaration of `<Card .../>` in your code

Comment: It should be called when rendering ColorExtractor?   <ColorExtractor
    src={this.props.merchant.merchant.coverPhoto}
    getColors={colors => this.lightestColor(colors)}
  />

Comment: nop, `getColors={colors => this.lightestColor(colors)}` will simply create a function, `lightestColor` will be called when `getColors` will be called not when it will be declared

Comment: And I mentioned that <Card /> is a child a few steps below <CardRow /> - I can include the code showing that, but I didn't feel it would be helpful. I can absolutely confirm that lightestColor() is getting called at least once.

Comment: Does the `ColorExtractor` component calls `props.getColors` method ?

Comment: Ok, but theoretically getColors should be called every time <ColorExtractor /> is rendered, no? I am going based off this library: https://github.com/nitin42/react-color-extractor

Comment: Ah, I believe so, the library has this function: ColorExtractor.defaultProps = {
 onError: function onError(error) {},
 // Colors can be in vec3 format (rgb or hsl) or in hex format
 getColors: function getColors(colors) {},
 rgb: false,
 hex: true,
 src: null,
 maxColors: 64
}; - again, lightestColor() is absolutely, without a shadow of a doubt getting called once.

Comment: could you add `onError={error => console.log(error)}` to `ColorExtractor` to see if there is a problem while processing the images

Comment: Here's the error generated: Error: Cannot load buffer as an image in browser
    at BrowserImage.load (browser.js:87)
    at ColorExtractor._this.useDefaultImageClass (react-color-extractor.es.js:73)
    at eval (react-color-extractor.es.js:67)

Comment: Hrm, the images are otherwise rendering correctly in the background of the cards, but apparently ColorExtractor is choking on them?

Comment: yep, there is an opened issue related to this subject https://github.com/nitin42/react-color-extractor/issues/2

Comment: Hrm, but I am not passing a buffer? I'm passing actual image links.

Comment: Image Links
Card.js:156 https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/wantify-public/burger.png
Card.js:155 Image Links
Card.js:156 https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com//wantify-public/merchants/25/cover-photo.jpg
Card.js:155 Image Links
Card.js:156 https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/wantify-public/bakery.png

As you can see here, these are all real images

Comment: yep, maybe a problem with the library, it has only one contributor and hasn't be updated for 9 months... maybe you could try https://github.com/colorjs/get-image-colors which also has only 1 contributor. or https://github.com/akfish/node-vibrant/ which seems to have more stars

Comment: Switching to get-image-colors solved the problem. And made my workflow much easier. Thank you!